# PyQt5 dialog widgets look glitchy when run with pyuic

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

So I'm making an app in PyQt5, which has a dialog. But the dialog is looking really glitchy when run with pyuic.

Here's a video of what's going on: https://youtu.be/3oJ7EMiJxO0
As you can see, the dialog shows fine with the "preview" function, but when I run it with python and pyuic, the labels and dropdowns are unusably glitchy. The button seems to work fine though...

I'm running Fedora 23 Workstation with GNOME 3, and Python 2.7.

Here's the contents of my .ui file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <author>David Teresi</author>
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>258</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>backflip Settings</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>-90</x>
     <y>260</y>
     <width>341</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>241</width>
     <height>261</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="title">
    <string>backflip Settings</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="layoutWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>155</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="UpdateEveryLabel">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Update every</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="UpdateEverySelect">
       <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Day</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Week</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Hour</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Minute</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="RefreshButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>230</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Refresh</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>109</width>
      <height>22</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="ThemeLabel">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Theme</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="ThemeSelect">
       <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>None</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Buildings</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Food</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Nature</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Technology</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>People</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>248</x>
     <y>254</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>157</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>316</x>
     <y>260</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>286</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from you Designer file that neither your `QDialog` or `QGroupBox` have a layout assigned.  They should be using `QVBoxLayout`'s.  You probably need to add some Vertical spacers as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding a vertical layout. (didn't know about layouts before!)

Comment: Aaaand... it works! Looks a bit different (widgets expand to fill the available space) but not altogether bad. Thanks!